# Cron send email with STDERR but NOT STDOUT?

Tags: email, scripting, cron, stderr

I have some python scripts that run on a daily basis in cron.  How can I have cron send me an email *ONLY WHEN THERE IS STDERR OUTPUT* from my script?  I want to be able to mail multiple recipients, and set the subject line individually for each cron entry.

I tried this:

```
./prog > /dev/null | mail . . .
```

but it didn't work -- I still receive blank emails when there is no STDERR.  Do I need to do this in the script itself?

Sorry if this seems basic, I have googled a lot but can't seem to find this answered succintly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The  `-s`  file test will tell you if a file exists and has size greater than zero.

```
./prog >/dev/null 2>some/file ; if [ -s some/file ] ; then mail < some/file ; fi
```

Comment: I ended up using a variant of this approach.  Thanks mobrule

Comment: found a good article on this which helped me..
http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/

Answer (score 26):

For cron you don't need to pipe through mail.  The cron daemon will automatically mail any output of your command to you.  Your crontab entry should look like:

```
# every minute
* * * * * ./prog >/dev/null
```

If there is no STDERR output, you won't get any mail.

Comment: "If there is no STDERR output, you won't get any mail."

That's true, if I set MAILTO="me@mine".  However, it is NOT true if piping to mail(1).

"In addition to LOGNAME, HOME, and SHELL, cron will look at MAILTO if it has any reason to send mail as a result of running commands in `this' crontab."  -- http://ss64.com/osx/crontab.html

However, I need to set the _subject_ of the mail, and there is no way to do this (IMHO) with cron itself.   So I'm stuck using mail, which loops us back to my original question.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it assumes `stdout` won't contain any useful information in case of an error. `cronic` solution worked for me better.

Answer (score 17):

You are asking incorrect question. When you are using mail(1) to send the email, it is no longer relevant that its in cron. What you actually need is to pipe stderr to stdin of mail. Normal pipe is from stdout to stdin, so simplest way to solve this is redirect:

`{ /prog > /dev/null ; } 2>&1 | mail ...`

Or in the less-clear way because of confusing order of redirectings:

`/prog 2>&1 > /dev/null | mail ...`

Comment: Great answer and the proper technique to direct both stderr and stdout to the mail command. The second example drops stdout on the floor and only sends stderr to the mail command.

Comment: I think that was the intent.

Answer (score 16):

mail v1.6 has an option to not send messages with an empty body:

```
 -E      Do not send messages with an empty body.  
         This is useful for piping errors from cron(8) scripts.
```

This might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice tool called [cronic](http://habilis.net/cronic/) that does this. It is part of the [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04, it's ``chronic`` (not ``cronic``) that is bundled in ``moreutils``, it's written in perl rather than bash, but seems to have the same purpose. Thanks anyway !

Comment: `chronic` seems to output both STDOUT and STDERR if the program exits with an error, or neither if the program exits cleanly. That didn't work for me. I wanted a `chronic` that filters out STDOUT, independent of the exit code. A simple redirect worked best for me.

Comment: Note that behavior of `cronic` and `chronic` is different: `chronic` (`moreutils`, Perl) doesn't output anything if exit code is 0, even if there was something on STDERR. `cronic` ([habilis.net](http://habilis.net/cronic/), bash) outputs everything if there was something on STDERR, even if exit code is 0.

Answer (score -2):

If your SCRIPT has commands that may produce STDERR that you want to be notified on, then you need to use a mail or mailx call within the script itself (if then else or ).  The cron job STDOUT and STDERR redirects are ONLY for cron job *EXECUTION* STDOUT and STDERR.  hkmaly had it right on the n